# Vector-kind Class structure in C#, multi-dimensional

Tags: c#, list, vector

I would like to initialize a C++-kind-of-multi-dimensional vector in C# as a Class (Teachers), where one particular teacher (member) can teach one or several subjects, let' say:

Teacher A teaches Biology
but
Teacher B teaches Biology and Math (and so forth)

I would like the user to input the subjects, so that the user can increment the number of subjects as he wishes and that this "list" can be be alphabetically ordered to the teacher names.

Would that be a Class Structure and if yes, how?

Comment: Can you post the c++ code to convert?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking for multidimensional arrays, which you can declare in C#, but this isn't making use of the power of classes:

```
var teachers = new string[2][];
teachers[0] = new [] {"Biology"};
teachers[1] = new[] { "Biology" , "Maths"};
```

Better would be to maintain collections of teachers and subjects, and then use Linq to return the teacher-subject pairs in whatever order you require. I have kept the subjects as strings, but you might, in a real life situation, want to encapsulate them in a class as well.

```
void Main
{    
  School school = new School();
  school.Add("Harry", "Quiddich");
  school.Add("Ron", "Quiddich");
  school.Add("Neville", "Herbology");
  school.Add("Hermione", "Herbology");
  school.Add("Hermione", "Divination");

  var orderedTeachers =
       school.Teachers.OrderBy(t => t.TeacherName)
            .SelectMany(
                x => x.Subjects.OrderBy(s => s).Select(s => new {Teacher = x.TeacherName, Subject = s}));
}

internal class School
{
    internal List<string> TaughtSubjects { get; } = new List<string>();
    internal List<Teacher> Teachers { get; } = new List<Teacher>();

    internal void Add(string teacherName, string subjectName)
    {
        // check to see if we have alreay defined this subject
        var subject = TaughtSubjects.SingleOrDefault(s => s == subjectName);

        // else create the subject and add to the school curriculum
        if (subject == null)
        {
            subject = subjectName;
            TaughtSubjects.Add(subject);
        }

        // check to see if the teacher is already on the school payroll
        var teacher = Teachers.SingleOrDefault(s => s.TeacherName == teacherName);

        // if not then add him or her
        if (teacher == null)
        {
            teacher = new Teacher(teacherName);
            Teachers.Add(teacher);
        }

        // check that the teacher isn't already down for teaching that subject before making the link
        if (!teacher.Subjects.Contains(subject))
            teacher.Subjects.Add(subject);
    }
}
internal class Teacher
{
    internal Teacher(string teacherName)
    {
        TeacherName = teacherName;
    }
    internal string TeacherName { get; }

    public List<string> Subjects { get; } = new List<string>();
}
```